# App crashes in release apk which run correctly in debug mode

Tags: android, android-studio

I have tested my app in debug mode. I have made debuggable as true in  release build type in build.gradle file. When I run and test it it gives me following error

```
2022-10-20 13:17:16.300 26285-26285/com.metamagics.patientsapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.metamagics.patientsapp, PID: 26285
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.List com.metamagics.pulsepatientsapp.d.h.a()' on a null object reference
        at com.metamagics.pulsepatientsapp.fragments.a.V1(:487)
        at com.metamagics.pulsepatientsapp.fragments.a$f.c(:1657)
        at com.metamagics.pulsepatientsapp.utilities.b.b(:129)
        at com.metamagics.pulsepatientsapp.utilities.b.onPostExecute(:10)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:771)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$900(AsyncTask.java:199)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:788)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8057)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:620)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1011)
```

I am not able to understand the issue, if anyone knows a better way to identify the error, I will be thankful.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you debug a release build, it will still be minified according to your build.gradle file. Try to first set minifyEnabled = false for your release configuration. Probably the Stacktrace gives you the reason of your error. If not you might need to configure your proguard rules if minify is needed.